# Unable to run null SDK tool. One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries. Please fix the underlying issue and retry

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, windows-7

Android Studio version 4.1 is giving the following error after installing and downloading the Sdk files:

```
Unable to run null SDK tool.
One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries.
Please fix the underlying issue and retry.
```

I am trying this on a Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit. I have tried 3 times but to no avail. If I cancel, then the gradle build fails and I am also unable to create a Virtual Device. How do I install the missing libraries and what are those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) and reinstall android studio or reinstall manually the sdk instead.